# Can users access and change component properties in an Angular app in production?

Tags: angular, security, state, client-side

I'm learning Angular and SPA's in general and I hope someone can provide me some guidance and educate me on this particular topic.

For an Angular app in development, I am aware that we are able to select a Component in order to access its state/properties and methods using `ng.getComponent(component)` whereby ng is accessible at the global scope.

As far as I am aware, the **ng ** namespace is not available during production.

Are there other ways that end users would be able to access and thereby change an Angular application's state in production?

If  so, how are we  able to protect our application's state?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Hi Leslie Bong, Could you add an explication on the reason why you would like to "protect your application's state?", as reminder security issue should always be checked in the api side, and not in the front-end.

Comment: Hi Raphaël, thank you for taking some time to respond. 

Please bear with me as I am self taught. The reason I ask is because I was thinking about implementation for certain scenarios. 

I was just wondering as an example in e-commerce - For instance, users changing price of products from the front end and then trying to add those products to cart, and then send a "make purchase" request to the back end with false values. This could totally happen right?

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet but yes based on what you said which I agree, security should be handled on the API side and back end. Does this mean that for an E-Commerce platform the back end also needs to query for latest data based on what was requested from the front end and perform its own logic to arrive at the final price before responding back to the client?

In such a scenario, then am I thinking too far in trying to protect the front end application state?


Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a component state through the browser after it have being compile in production mode.

### Extras

To get a bit further, *and also to give responses to the main comments*

You can try to protect the front-end the way you want, fact is, that doesn't matter.

A hacker won't be changing the ui, but the request he send to the server. at some time in an e-commerce, you'll have to send to request to the server, which will then be taken by your api which will deal with those information.

The **only data** that should transit should be the **token** of the user & the **id of the item/s** the user want to buy. The **api should calculate the rest**, so basically, you will have to do the calculation 2 times, 1. in the front *(I would request the API to send me the total amount)* and 1 in the backend.